# UITableViewCell's content resizes after reopening IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uilabel

Sometimes, when opening my storyboard in interface builder, along with the typical version change some `UILables` change their width and become smaller.

This may have something to do with the update to Yosemite and Xcode 6.1, since the problematic `UILabels` didn't use to change their size on their own.

This is the structure where the labels are included (the marked labels are the ones causing problems):
[image]

All three have following Autoresizing properties:

[image]

Does someone know why this is happening, and how to make it stop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Xcode bug.

In previous versions a table cell would be generated like this:

```
<tableViewCell ...>
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
    ...
    <tableViewCellContentView ...>
          <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
```

with the new version the `rect` tag within the `tableViewCellContentView` is missing completely. After I inserted it manually, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Experienced same bug yesterday, after adding the missing property, it even not change when you change cell height in storyboard. Hope anyone ticketed Apple. Not sure if it's fixed in Xcode 6.2

Comment: There is a ticket regarding this bug at Apple's bug reporting system with id 18404033 (currently still in "Open" state)